# Umbraco 6 Razor Master Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

Trying to get Umbraco working with MVC/Razor.  Everything is working ok except that the backend is showing empty templates.  Is there any way to get Umbraco to allow editing the Razor partial views in the Templates folder in the Settings section?

Answer (score 0):

turns out we just needed to wait a bit after changing the defaultRenderingEngine tag